# WPF Microsoft Charting Line Chart with Error Bars

Tags: wpf, charts

Does anyone know how I can add Error bars like these:
http://www.officetooltips.com/images/tips/83_3/1.png

with the Microsoft WPF charting toolkit? Can you give me a simple code example please?

I've found some info here, but can't seem to utilize the info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456729.aspx

Hope someone can help
Many thanks in advance.